# Copy and move a file from SFTP using Java config in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I am new to Spring integration. I've this requirement to first move a file from /files folder to /process folder in SFTP location and then copy that file to local.
I am suggested to use gateway and configuration has to be in java using annotations.
I have tried seeking for answers here on stackoverflow but couldn't find something relevant.
However I was able to copy the file using @InboundChannelAdapter and by configuring other beans.

Below is the code I have written so far

Configuration
public class SftpConfiguration {

```
@Value("${ftp.file.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${ftp.file.port")
private int port;

@Value("${ftp.file.user")
private String user;

@Value("${ftp.file.password")
private String password;

@Value("${directorry.file.remote")
private String remoteDir;

@Value("${directorry.file.in.pollerDelay")
final private String pollerDelay = "1000";

@Value("${directory.file.remote.move}")
private String toMoveDirectory;

@Bean
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(host);
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setUser(user);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
}

@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDir);
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xlsx"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = pollerDelay))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
            sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());

    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            try {
                new FtpOrderRequestHandler().handle((File) message.getPayload());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handlerOut() {
    return new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "mv", toMoveDirectory);
}
```

}

I will appreciate any tips or suggestion .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and the following worked for me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SftpConfiguration {

    @Value("${config.adapter.ftp.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${config.adapter.ftp.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${config.adapter.ftp.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${config.adapter.ftp.password}")
    private String password;

    @Autowired
    private FtpOrderRequestHandler handler;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Value("${config.adapter.ftp.excel.sourceFolder}")
    private String sourceDir;

    @Value("${config.adapter.ftp.excel.localFolder}")
    private String localDir;

    @Value("${config.adapter.ftp.excel.backupFolder}")
    private String backupDir;

    @Value("${config.adapter.ftp.statusExcel.destinationFolder}")
    private String statusDest;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpConfiguration.class);


    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(user);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sourceDir);
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xlsx"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "${config.cron.cataligent.order}"), autoStartup = "true")
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(localDir));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handlerOrder() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                try {
                    SFTPGateway gateway = context.getBean(SFTPGateway.class);
                    final File orderFile = (File) message.getPayload();
                    gateway.sendToSftp(orderFile);
                    LOGGER.debug("{} is picked by scheduler and moved to {} folder",orderFile.getName(),backupDir);
                    handler.handle((File) message.getPayload());
                    handler.deleteFileFromLocal((File) message.getPayload());
                    LOGGER.info("Processing of file {} is completed",orderFile.getName());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error occurred while processing order file exception is {}",e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannelDest")
    public MessageHandler handlerOrderBackUp() {
        SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(backupDir));
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannelStatus")
    public MessageHandler handlerOrderStatusUS() {
        SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(statusDest));
        return handler;
    }



    @MessagingGateway
    public interface SFTPGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannelDest")
        void sendToSftp(File file);

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannelStatus")
        void sendToSftpOrderStatus(File file);

    }

}
```

I have used this for picking up a file from SFTP location. Saving it at local. Then moving the file to backup folder and then processing the whole file. After processing deleted the file from the local.

I have used gateway(@MessagingGateway) for file movement and I have two different methods in that interface. One for moving the same file to backup folder and other method is to move another file(a status file) in my code to desired SFTP location. I've tried to keep the code clean for better understanding.

Comment: Can you please help me. I am getting this exception everytime - o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing '/foo' to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.util.PoolItemNotAvailableException: Failed to obtain pooled item

Comment: @thedevd may I know what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NaveenHanda Could you pls share your git url to see the working sample..

Comment: @Saravanan I've used this in my project so it is not available on git, but this is exact replica out of it and it is still working. In case you need some other help please let me know.

Comment: @NaveenHanda : Thanks Naveen. Am new to Spring integration and spring batch too. I just want to read files from sftp location and save it into my local drive.Could you pls help me to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

Right, you need to use `@Bean` with the `@InboundChannelAdapter` for the `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` to download files from the remote `/process` folder to local directory. This is done on the poller basis and is a separate process, fully not related to the move operation. That move logic you can perform via `FtpOutboundGateway` with the `MV` command:

> The *mv* command has no options.
>
> The *expression* attribute defines the "from" path and the *rename-expression* attribute defines the "to" path.
>   By default, the *rename-expression* is `headers['file_renameTo']`.
>   This expression must not evaluate to null, or an empty `String`.
>   If necessary, any remote directories needed will be created.
>   The payload of the result message is `Boolean.TRUE`.
>   The original remote directory is provided in the `file_remoteDirectory` header, and the filename is provided in the `file_remoteFile` header.
>   The new path is in the `file_renameTo` header.

This one you have to use via:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new SftpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "mv", "'my_remote_dir/my_file'");
}
```

Comment: Artem Bilan I see your point here. So you suggest to use SftpOutboundGateway to move my file to /process folder from /files folder.  My query is first we pick file from /file using @InboundChannelAdapter 
and then SftpOutboundGateway moves to it to desired location say /process.
And now I want to copy that file to local from /process.
How will that happen.

I'm adding the code I have written by far into my question. Please take a look and suggest what changes should I make to copy the moved file to local from /process.

Comment: I don't see problems in your code so far. However if you talk about local `/files` directory, then yes you have to use `FileReadingMessageSource` and send those local files to the remote `/process` via `SftpMessageHandler`. On the other side you definitely can continue to use `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` to poll remote files from `/process` to local dir. Otherwise, please, rephrase your requirements and consider this my comment as I just don't understand the task

Comment: Hi artem let me try to explain again. Consider you have two folders on sftp named /initial and /final and one folder at local caller /local. Now requirement is to first move file from /initial to /final. And then copy that file from /final to /local. I hope this helps you understand the problem better. Now requirement in place do u think the above code is correct.

Comment: Well, then no: you use `sftpChannel` wrong way. 1. You have to use `MV` command for the `SftpOutboundGateway` to more remote file from one remote fir to another. You should send the file name to move into this Gateway. The `SftpIbboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` should look into the target remote dir and it will sync remote files to local dir producing messages with them at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much @Artem. Could you please tell me how to pass the source file name to the gateway??

Comment: It should be as a `payload` of the message to send. The `SftpOutboundGateway` must be configured for expression as `payload` as well. See Reference Manual for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

Comment: Hi Artem. I tried things, but I am unable give the source directory to SftpOutboundGateway. Could you please suggest any other way which would solve my problem.

Comment: The source directory is a part of input. See my sample in the answer - `"'my_remote_dir/my_file'"`. The `my_remote_dir` is the source dir. The `my_file` is a file to move. You also need to use `setRenameExpressionString()`, for example like `'/remoteTarget/my_file'`. That's all about the static path. For the more comprehensive use-case you should consider to send the remote paths and file name as a request message payload/headers and therefore make those expressions based on the data in the message.